# Configure `.npmrc` to get one scoped package module from npm and the others from github packages

Tags: npm, github-package-registry, .npmrc

I'm using a scoped package in my application, some modules from it are stored on GitHub packages and the rest are in npm registry. Till now I was using only one module that is stored on GitHub, but now I need to install another one stored on npm.
Currently my `.npmrc` file looks like this:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@custompackage:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

I want to inform `npm` to install specific scoped module from npm registry and keep installing others from GitHub packages. Updating `.npmrc` like this doesn't work (it continues looking the subpackage on GitHub):

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@custompackage:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
@custompackage/module1:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Is it possible at all to configure `.npmrc` to get a part of scoped package modules from npm and the rest from GitHub pages?